# How to get colour values from tailwind config file

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I want to access the value of the "accent" colour from the config file so I can assign it to a new colour. I have tried `danger: theme('colors.accent')` but I'm getting this error `> theme is not defined`. I want to avoid hard coding the hex colour code again. Is there a way to do this easily?

tailwind.config.js

```
colors: {

accent: '#57A0D7',
accentlight: '#88BCE2',
accentdark: '#4B8CBD',
accentdarker: '#4682B0',

danger: theme(colors.accent),
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing. Just set the value you want to appear in multiple places outside of your `module.exports` and you can use it anywhere as a variable since the config file is just a js file.

```
const accent = '#57A0D7';

module.exports = {
  theme: {
   colors: {
    accent,
    accentlight: '#88BCE2',
    accentdark: '#4B8CBD',
    accentdarker: '#4682B0',
    danger: accent
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a function

```
colors: {

accent: '#57A0D7',
accentlight: '#88BCE2',
accentdark: '#4B8CBD',
accentdarker: '#4682B0',

danger: theme => theme('colors.accent'),
```

Comment: This actually creates output, but unfortunately `theme=>#57A0D7` instead of `#57A0D7`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
xxx: ({ theme }) => ({
  danger: theme(colors.accent),
})
```

In your example:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      accent: '#57A0D7',
      accentlight: '#88BCE2',
      accentdark: '#4B8CBD',
      accentdarker: '#4682B0',

      // ...
    },
    background: ({ theme }) => ({
      danger: theme(colors.accent),
    })
  }
}
```

As shown here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#referencing-other-values